# How to Inject my service to ExceptionHandler

Tags: angular

I used my service in other places injected automaticaly by angular 2.
I want to use the same service in ExceptionHandler.
But service doesn't post data to server.
I went through debuger and my service invokes.

```
class MyExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
  rbJSLogger: RBLoggerService;

  constructor() {
    super(null,null);
    var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      RBLoggerService,
      JSONP_PROVIDERS,
      Http,
      ConnectionBackend,
      HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ]);
    this.rbJSLogger = injector.get(RBLoggerService);
  }
  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null){
    // console.error(stackTrace);
    this.rbJSLogger.searchBy("asd");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update** `ExceptionHandler` was renamed to `ErrorHandler` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35239028/217408

**orgiginal**

This code

```ts
var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([...]);
```

creates a new independent injector that doesn't know anything about services provided in your Angular applications.

You might want to inject the injector used by Angular in your application like

```ts
class MyExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
  rbJSLogger: RBLoggerService;

  constructor(injector:Injector) {
    super(null,null);
    this.rbJSLogger = injector.get(RBLoggerService);
  }
  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null){
    // console.error(stackTrace);
    this.rbJSLogger.searchBy("asd");
  }
}
```

or just

```ts
class MyExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandler {
  rbJSLogger: RBLoggerService;

  constructor(private rbJSLogger:RBLoggerService) {
    super(null,null);
  }
  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null){
    // console.error(stackTrace);
    this.rbJSLogger.searchBy("asd");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used second variant.

Comment: If there are no special requirements then the 2nd variant is definitely the way to go but I was not sure from your question about that.